# Creating and combining rectangles based on a result of an edge detection

Tags: c#, performance

**Context**

In an imageprocessing project of mine, I needed to do some edge detection and implemented the [Theo Pavlidis algorithm](http://www.imageprocessingplace.com/downloads_V3/root_downloads/tutorials/contour_tracing_Abeer_George_Ghuneim/theo.html) which works quite well. A problem had been to get the next "good" position. Assuming an image like this (where the `1` represent the needed pixel value)

```
011110  
111111  
111111  
011110
```

this would result in the following edges found

```
011110  
100001      1111  
100001      1111    
011110
```

because the algorithm is searching for values which hadn't been visited and have the desired value `1` in it.

So I was in the need to find the enclosed area to exclude it from the algorithms *position search area*.

The algorithm returns a `IEnumerable<Position>` for each found value on the edge, where the `Position` struct looks like so

```
public struct Position
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;

    public Position(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    private static readonly Position empty = new Position(-1, -1);
    public static Position Empty
    {
        get
        {
            return empty;
        }
    }

    public static bool  operator ==(Position p1, Position p2){

        return (p1.X == p2.X) && (p1.Y == p2.Y);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Position p1, Position p2)
    {
        return !(p1.X == p2.X) && (p1.Y == p2.Y);
    }

}
```

So, nothing fancy at all.

My idea was to first create an `IEnumerable<Int32Rect>` out of the `IEnumerable<Position>` using the `Min` of `Position.X` of all positions with the same value of `Position.Y` to create the rectangles line by line form top to bottom.

**The meat**

The creation of the `IEnumerable<Int32Rect>` is done like so

```
private IEnumerable<Int32Rect> ToRectangles(IEnumerable<Position> positions)
{
    foreach (Position position in positions.Distinct(new PositionComparerY()).OrderBy(p => p.Y))
    {
        IEnumerable<Position> positionsWithSameY = positions.Where(p => p.Y == position.Y);
        int minX = positionsWithSameY.Min(x => x.X);
        int maxX = positionsWithSameY.Max(x => x.X);

        yield return new Int32Rect(minX, position.Y, maxX - minX + 1, 1);
    }
}
```

with the help of the `PositionComparerY` class which looks like so

```
private class PositionComparerY : IEqualityComparer<Position>
{
    public bool Equals(Position x, Position y)
    {
        return x.Y == y.Y;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Position position)
    {
        return position.Y.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

The next step I needed to take, was to combine the resulting `Int32Rect`'s if they have the same width and start at the same `x` position.

I implemented this by grouping the rectangles based on the `Width` property of the `Int32Rect` like so

```
private IEnumerable<Int32Rect> CombineRectangles(IEnumerable<Int32Rect> rectangles)
{
    var groupedRectangles = rectangles.OrderBy(r => r.Y)
                        .GroupBy(r => r.Width, rect => rect, (key, Rectangles) => new { Rectangles });

    Int32Rect emptyRect = new Int32Rect();

    foreach (var groupedRectangle in groupedRectangles)
    {

        Int32Rect lastRectangle = emptyRect;
        bool isFirstRectangleInRectangles = true;
        int y = 0;
        int rectangleHeight = 1;
        foreach (Int32Rect rectangle in groupedRectangle.Rectangles)
        {
            if (isFirstRectangleInRectangles)
            {
                lastRectangle = rectangle;
                y = rectangle.Y + 1;
                isFirstRectangleInRectangles = false;
                continue;
            }

            if (rectangle.Y != y)
            {
                yield return new Int32Rect(lastRectangle.X, lastRectangle.Y, lastRectangle.Width, rectangleHeight);
                lastRectangle = rectangle;
                rectangleHeight = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                rectangleHeight += 1;
            }
            y = rectangle.Y + 1;

        }

        if (lastRectangle != emptyRect) { yield return new Int32Rect(lastRectangle.X, lastRectangle.Y, lastRectangle.Width, rectangleHeight); ; }

    }
}
```

**The simple tests**

```
The needed edge positions 011110  
                          100001
                          100001
                          011110
```

will be produced like so

```
private IEnumerable<Position> GetTestPositions()
{

    List<Position> testPositions = new List<Position>();

    testPositions.Add(new Position(2, 3));
    testPositions.Add(new Position(3, 3));
    testPositions.Add(new Position(1, 3));
    testPositions.Add(new Position(4, 3));

    testPositions.Add(new Position(2, 0));
    testPositions.Add(new Position(3, 0));
    testPositions.Add(new Position(1, 0));
    testPositions.Add(new Position(4, 0));

    testPositions.Add(new Position(0, 1));
    testPositions.Add(new Position(1, 1));
    testPositions.Add(new Position(4, 1));
    testPositions.Add(new Position(5, 1));

    testPositions.Add(new Position(0, 2));
    testPositions.Add(new Position(1, 2));
    testPositions.Add(new Position(4, 2));
    testPositions.Add(new Position(5, 2));
    return testPositions;
}
```

and a test for the `ToRectangles()` method

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestToRectangles_Success()
{

    IEnumerable<Position> testPositions = GetTestPositions();

    List<Int32Rect> rectangles = ToRectangles(testPositions).ToList();

    int expectedRectangleCount = 4;
    string message = "Number of rectangles does not match. Expected {0} Found {1}";

    Assert.IsTrue(rectangles.Count == expectedRectangleCount, message, expectedRectangleCount, rectangles.Count);

    int expectedWidth = 4;
    message = "{0} rectangle width assert failed. Expected {1} found {2}";
    Assert.IsTrue(expectedWidth == rectangles[0].Width, message, "First", expectedWidth, rectangles[0].Width);
    Assert.IsTrue(expectedWidth == rectangles[3].Width, message, "Forth", expectedWidth, rectangles[1].Width);

    expectedWidth = 6;
    Assert.IsTrue(expectedWidth == rectangles[1].Width, message, "Second", expectedWidth, rectangles[2].Width);
    Assert.IsTrue(expectedWidth == rectangles[2].Width, message, "Third", expectedWidth, rectangles[3].Width);

}
```

and for the `CombineRectangles()` method

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestCombineRectangles_Success()
{
    IEnumerable<Int32Rect> rectangles = ToRectangles(GetTestPositions());
    List<Int32Rect> combinedRectangles = CombineRectangles(rectangles).ToList();

    string message = "Number of rectangles does not match. Expected {0} found {1}";
    int expectedRectanglesCount = 3;
    Assert.IsTrue(expectedRectanglesCount == combinedRectangles.Count, message, expectedRectanglesCount, combinedRectangles.Count);

    // Because the rectangles will be grouped based on the width
    // we expect the first and second rectangle to have height 1
    message = "{0} rectangle height assert failed. Expected {1} found {2}";
    int expectedHeight = 1;
    Assert.IsTrue(expectedHeight == combinedRectangles[0].Height, message, "First", expectedHeight, combinedRectangles[0].Height);
    Assert.IsTrue(expectedHeight == combinedRectangles[1].Height, message, "Second", expectedHeight, combinedRectangles[1].Height);

    expectedHeight = 2;
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedHeight, combinedRectangles[2].Height, message, "Third", expectedHeight, combinedRectangles[2].Height);

    message = "{0} rectangle assert failed. Expected {1} found {2}";
    Int32Rect expectedRectangle = new Int32Rect(1, 0, 4, 1);
    Assert.IsTrue(expectedRectangle == combinedRectangles[0], message, "First", expectedRectangle.ToString(), combinedRectangles[0].ToString());

    expectedRectangle = new Int32Rect(1, 3, 4, 1);
    Assert.IsTrue(expectedRectangle == combinedRectangles[1], message, "Second", expectedRectangle.ToString(), combinedRectangles[1].ToString());

    expectedRectangle = new Int32Rect(0, 1, 6, 2);
    Assert.IsTrue(expectedRectangle == combinedRectangles[2], message, "Third", expectedRectangle.ToString(), combinedRectangles[2].ToString());

}
```

**Conclusion**

Because this is used in imageprocessing speed is a major requirement, so my primary concern is **performance** wise (but in a readable and maintainable way), but feel free to point out any flaw you find.

**Clarifications based on comments**

> did you run a performance analysis on your code?

No, because I didn't implement this. These methods live at the moment only in a unit test to see if I am doing it correctly. The performance concerns are just of a general type to know if I use some obvious stupid approach which could be done much faster by some different algorithm.

> is there a reason why you don't use the already built-in Point struct (other than it's less meaningful name in your case)?

Not really, the only reason is the name and that I have full control over it.

Comment: Very nice question! I have two points regarding your question. First: did you run a performance analysis on your code? This can be really helpful to detect where your code might be running slow. Second point: is there a reason why you don't use the already built-in Point struct (other than its less meaningful name in your case)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Life could be so easy if everything would work like expected. The shown code is good and work successful for the given array, but fails for e.g

```
000011110  without the `0`     1111  
001001000                    1  1 
011110000                   1111
011110000                   1111
```

So we still need to find the enclosed area to exclude it from the algorithm.

For this problem a IMHO good approach is to use the [`PathGeometry`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pathgeometry%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class which has the [`FillContains()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms615660(v=vs.110).aspx) method to examine if a given point is inside the "path".

So I have created one extension methods like so

```
public static bool Contains(this IEnumerable<PathGeometry> geometries, Position position)
{
    Point point = new Point(position.X, position.Y);
    return geometries.Any(g=> g.FillContains(point));
}
```

to check if a given `Position` is contained in an `IEnumerable<PathGeometry>`.

The `ToPathGeometry()` extension method allows me to create a `PathGeometry` object by providing a starting position and the found positions like so

```
public static PathGeometry ToPathGeometry(this Position startPosition, IEnumerable<Position> foundPositions)
{

    IList<LineSegment> segements = new List<LineSegment>();
    foreach (Position p in foundPositions.Where(p => p != startPosition))
    {
        segements.Add(new LineSegment(new Point(p.X, p.Y), true));
    }

    PathFigure figure = new PathFigure(new Point(startPosition.X, startPosition.Y), segements, true);
    IList<PathFigure> figures = new List<PathFigure>();
    figures.Add(figure);

    return new PathGeometry(figures);

}
```

Which leads me also to the conclusion that it would be better to skip the `Position` class and instead use the `Point` class.

**Update**

Profiling my application resulted that the shown extension method

> ```
> public static bool Contains(this IEnumerable<PathGeometry> geometries, Position position)
> {
>     Point point = new Point(position.X, position.Y);
>     return geometries.Any(g=> g.FillContains(point));
> }
> ```

is a bottleneck. So I changed it to

```
public static bool Contains(this IEnumerable<PathGeometry> geometries, Position position)
{
    Point point = new Point(position.X, position.Y);
    return geometries.Any(g=> g.Bounds.Contains(point));
}
```

which reduced the execution time to 1/15 .